# Crop Landscape Image Dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, crop

I want to crop Image according to red View . There are some points to keep in mind.

1.Image can be scrolled and Zoomed.
2.Red ImageView is created Dynamically according to Image

```
 UIImage* whole = [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]; //I uses this image
 CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(whole.CGImage, CGRectMake(x, y, incX, incY));
 UIImage* part = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
```

I just want to know How to find the  Values of

x, y, incX, incY

Thanks...

Scenario 1: Normal (Not Scrolled)

[image]

Expected Result (Ignore Black Border On Top and Bottom)
[image]

Scenario 2:Scrolled

[image]

Expected Result (Ignore Black Border On Top and Bottom)

[image]

Scenario 3: Zoomed

[image]

And same  Expected Result for the Zoomed One.

In all cases I want the respective Images Inside the Red Rectangle.

For all These I am Using this Code...

```
    -(void)cropClicked:(UIButton*)sender
    {
        float zoomScale = 1.0 / [mainScrollView zoomScale];
        CGRect rect;
        rect.size.width = [redImageView bounds].size.width * zoomScale ;
        rect.size.height = [redImageView bounds].size.height * zoomScale ;
        rect.origin.x = ([mainScrollView bounds].origin.x + redImageView.frame.origin.x );
        rect.origin.y = ([mainScrollView bounds].origin.y + redImageView.frame.origin.y );

        CGImageRef cr = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([[mainImageView image] CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cr];
        mainImageView.image=cropped;
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cropped, nil, nil, nil);
        CGImageRelease(cr);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to let the user draw that rect?

Comment: No @HDdeveloper I want the point when the redImage's X and Y is there on screen, whether it is scrolled or zoomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as @HDdeveloper rightly said, you can use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`. This take 2 params, the first is the whole image, the second is the frame that you want to crop (so probably the frame of your red imageView).
The problem is that if you're targeting for both retina/non retina; if your whole image is an image @2x and you want to crop the image with the red imageview frame you have to double your frame to get the right screenshot.
So you can try with this method:

```
//Define the screen type:
#define isRetinaDisplay [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)

- (UIImage*)cropInnerImage:(CGRect)rect {
    //Take a screenshot of the whole image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage* ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGRect rct;
    //Double the frame if you're in retina display
    if (isRetinaDisplay) {
        rct=CGRectMake(rect.frame.origin.x*2, rect.frame.origin.y*2, rect.size.width*2, rect.size.height*2);
    } else {
        rct=rect;
    }
    //Crop the image from the screenshot
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([ret CGImage], rct);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    //Save and open the result images with Preview.app
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(result) writeToFile: @"/tmp/testCrop.png" atomically: YES];
    system("open /tmp/testCrop.png");
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(ret) writeToFile: @"/tmp/testRet.png" atomically: YES];
    system("open /tmp/testRet.png");
    //
    return result;
}
```

Where the `rect` parameter must be your red image frame, and `self.view.frame` must be the equal to the `wholeImageView.frame`. You can skip the last 4 lines, these are just to see in your Mac what you're cropping.

PS: i use this method to crop an image and set it as background of UIView, this is the reason i have to double the `frame`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mat but how can i calculate the rect which is being passed to this method which is not the redImage's Rect

Comment: if i pass redImage Rect then Image will be always cropped with x and y of redImage and as I already mentioned my image can be scalled and Zoomed also

Comment: so i m looking for the exact X and Y for the rect Height and width can be derived from zoom scale of ScrollView

Comment: So in Total i want the point when the redImage's X and Y is there on screen, whether it is scrolled or zoomed.

Comment: What is the image that the user can zoom?The whole image or the cropped red image? Anyway if you're putting the red imageView on the screen, surely you also have the x,y of the frame, you could use a `CGRect` ivar to keep track of the last frame set to the imageView and pass it to the method.

Comment: No User can't Move Red View,User can only scroll back image and also can zoom In-Out

Comment: So i don't understand what is the result image that you want even if the user scrolls/zoom, can you post an example of a possible resulting image?

Comment: yes sure i can mail you the code also if you can provide me your email,I have made a sample demo project for this so I can sent you that,and Thanks again for helping

Comment: Yes sure, but cant you use dropbox and share a folder? In this way everybody can help you! (my email addr is in my profile).

Comment: can you invite me for a chat so we can discuss more on this i m really in need of the Help.And Your Email is probably not shown in your profile.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20394/discussion-between-mat-and-anand)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CGImageRef
pass your rect in the whole image. Then call this on button click

```
UIImage* whole = [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"]; //I uses this image
    CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(whole.CGImage, CGRectMake(x, y, incX, incY));
    UIImage* part = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest but ,I want know how you find  x, y, incX, incY

Comment: @Anand, you can use the image zoom scale to determine that.