# Force square image from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I think I have a similar problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220958/force-uiimagepickercontroller-to-crop-a-square-image) other question's title suggests, but the accepted answer is not at all what I need.
I want to "force" the user to use a square image. Currently, when choosing a horizontally "longer" image (landscape image), one could theoretically make a selection with black bars top and bottom which results in a selected image that is NOT squared.

Here my code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selected: UIImage?

    if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        selected = img
        selected = UIImage.imgToSquare(image: selected)
        doSomethingWithImage(selected!)
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

UIImage.imgToSquare(image: UIImage) is an Extension that I have and use as a temporary fallback but it would be much more elegant if the "maximum pinch/zoom-out" gives a square image.



To whoever marked this as a duplicate.. In which way is this a duplicate? I could not find a solution on this on the whole internet, and what you linked was not related to UIImagePickerController....
I already said I'm able to crop an image to a square already with my Extension (UIImage.imgToSquare(image: UIImage))....
But what I want, is the image SELECTION to always be square.
I'll attach a screenshot.


What I have: [image: What I have]

What I want: [image]


(the second one - what I want - would still be scrollable horizontally)

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the option that allows editing and use content mode scaleAspectFill on your imageView. Or implement your own cropping

Comment: Because I'd like my user to select a square part of his image which is not necessarily in the center. Maybe there's something I can set on the UIImagePicker that only allows square selection (without black parts on top and bottom)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20056870/2303865

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824287/how-to-crop-image-after-taken-from-uiimagepicker-camera

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/13640754/2303865

Answer (score -2):

I think this will helpful for you..

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    var myimage:UIImage!

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        myImageView.image = pickedImage
        myimage = pickedImage
    }

    // So the user can pick only Square Image not others
    if myimage.size.height == myimage.size.width
    {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so this would basically do what I’m currently doing with UIImage.imgToSquare(image: UIImage) right? But I like the approach... :)

Comment: But this approach will restrict user pick only Square images.